# Users Ultra: Hide asterisk for required registration fields?

Tags: plugins, users, user-registration

All of the fields in my [Users Ultra](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-ultra/) registration form are required. It makes no sense to place an asterisk on all of them. Is there a way to remove the asterisks?

Comment: 3rd Party Plugins are considered off-topic here. Do you have a link to your form? It might be doable via CSS. Does this plugin support placeholders? You may be able to overwrite the placeholder to something custom.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the registration shortcote output with your own callable function and return a str_replace modified output.

Comment: wow, I didn't almost anything you said. I am a novice in wordpress. Can you give a little more detail?